# Read XML file from android assets folder and send to server

Tags: android, xml, assets

I have created a XML file in assets folder and I want to read that file and fetch the contents and send details to server..

How can I do that in android

Comment: Is your issue in reading the file or sending it to a server? Please be more specific and show us some code/research/an attempt to answer your own question.

Comment: @mbs first i want to read the xml node wise

Answer (score 0):

I am writing some code to read a file from assets .. It may help you..

```
//Open your file from  assets as  input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

By using this input stream u can read your file from assets folder..